# How do i wrangle this messy df?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

How do I convert these messy dataframe from string into the proposed dataframe in the bottom?

Module

```
import pandas as pad
import io
```

String data

```
test = '\tStart\t \t \tStop\n\t12/12/20 1400\t\t\nrugby  \n\t12/16/20 1359\n\t12/12/20 1300\t\t\nsoccer \n\t12/19/20 0859\n\t12/12/20 1300\t\t\nbasketball \n\t12/19/20 0659\n\n\n\n'
```

Turning into pandas dataframe

```
test_raw = io.StringIO(test)
test_df = pad.read_csv(test, sep='\t')

test_df

    Unnamed: 0          Start       .1  Stop
0          NaN  12/12/20 1400 NaN  NaN   NaN
1      rugby              NaN NaN  NaN   NaN
2          NaN  12/16/20 1359 NaN  NaN   NaN
3          NaN  12/12/20 1300 NaN  NaN   NaN
4      soccer             NaN NaN  NaN   NaN
5          NaN  12/19/20 0859 NaN  NaN   NaN
6          NaN  12/12/20 1300 NaN  NaN   NaN
7  basketball             NaN NaN  NaN   NaN
8          NaN  12/19/20 0659 NaN  NaN   NaN
```

How do I turn it into:

```
           Start       Sport           Stop
0  12/12/20 1400       rugby  12/16/20 1359
1  12/12/20 1300      soccer  12/19/20 0859
2  12/12/20 1300  basketball  12/19/20 0659
```

Thank you in advance@

Comment: I think you should split on \n instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = '\tStart\t \t \tStop\n\t12/12/20 1400\t\t\nrugby  \n\t12/16/20 1359\n\t12/12/20 1300\t\t\nsoccer \n\t12/19/20 0859\n\t12/12/20 1300\t\t\nbasketball \n\t12/19/20 0659\n\n\n\n'

# step1 split test by \n
alist = test.split('\n')

    # ['\tStart\t \t \tStop',
    
    #  '\t12/12/20 1400\t\t',
    #  'rugby  ',
    #  '\t12/16/20 1359',
    
    #  '\t12/12/20 1300\t\t',
    #  'soccer ',
    #  '\t12/19/20 0859',
    
    #  '\t12/12/20 1300\t\t',
    #  'basketball ',
    #  '\t12/19/20 0659',
    
    #  '',
    #  '',
    #  '',
    #  '']



# step2 we can see that every row has a location index rule
# 1. Start with index of 1, 4, ..., 1+3n
# 2. Sport with index of 2, 5, ..., 2+3n
# 3. Stop  with index of 3, 6, ..., 3+3n

Start_col1 = alist[1::3] # -> ['\t12/12/20 1400\t\t', '\t12/12/20 1300\t\t', '\t12/12/20 1300\t\t', '', '']
Sport_col2 = alist[2::3] # -> ['rugby  ', 'soccer ', 'basketball ', '']
Stop_col3 = alist[3::3]  # -> ['\t12/16/20 1359', '\t12/19/20 0859', '\t12/19/20 0659', '']

# step3 use zip to combine the same location index in a tuple
blist = list(zip(Start_col1, Sport_col2, Stop_col3))
# [('\t12/12/20 1400\t\t', 'rugby  ', '\t12/16/20 1359'),
#  ('\t12/12/20 1300\t\t', 'soccer ', '\t12/19/20 0859'),
#  ('\t12/12/20 1300\t\t', 'basketball ', '\t12/19/20 0659'),
#  ('', '', '')]

# step4 convert to dataframe
dfn = pd.DataFrame(blist)
print(dfn)
#                     0            1                2
# 0  \t12/12/20 1400\t\t      rugby    \t12/16/20 1359
# 1  \t12/12/20 1300\t\t      soccer   \t12/19/20 0859
# 2  \t12/12/20 1300\t\t  basketball   \t12/19/20 0659
# 3                                                   

# step5 strip space 
dfn = dfn.applymap(str.strip)
print(dfn)

#                0           1              2
# 0  12/12/20 1400       rugby  12/16/20 1359
# 1  12/12/20 1300      soccer  12/19/20 0859
# 2  12/12/20 1300  basketball  12/19/20 0659
# 3                                          

# step6 delete null rows
cond = dfn[1] == ''
dfn = dfn[~cond]
print(dfn)

#                0           1              2
# 0  12/12/20 1400       rugby  12/16/20 1359
# 1  12/12/20 1300      soccer  12/19/20 0859
# 2  12/12/20 1300  basketball  12/19/20 0659

# step7 set columns of the DataFrame
dfn.columns = ['Start', 'Sport', 'Stop']
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27930101)